# AEM:: Unable to change languages in Language Grid

Tags: aem

I have a set of languages that I would like to be visible in the Language Grid under http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/i18n/translator.html. I am following the directions given here at the URL http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/components/i18n/translator.html under "Managing Supported Languages". The issue is when I am trying to add the property "languages" to the node /etc/languages, the AEM is showing a red mark with the message "No property definition found." I am using AEM 6. How do I go about this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a sling:folder instead of nt:folder.